"Buffering" raster category of raster layer in QGIS
In this raster with 300m resolution, I would like to increase the size of one category (1), creating an (approximately) 1km buffer increase. In other words: I would like to expand the borders of category 1 by 1km, without separating it from the original layer.
I saw a possibly similar question but it is in ArcMap and I didn't understand it.
Also, this layer is not the lightest, so any tips on optimizing computational effort in this process?

As I understand it your raster layer has other categories? Do you want to buffer for analysis purposes? In that case I would polygonize it buffer just the category you want and then rasterize the buffered layer with the same resolution as your initial layer. Then you should be able to merge both raster layers.

You could do it in three steps with QGIS GRASS Processing tools:

r.reclass
Reclassify the landcover to 1 and NULL
Reclass rules text:
1   = 1  Buffer this
*  = NULL



r.buffer
Buffer that 1 value by 1000m (ellipsoidal geodesic distance)


r.mapcalc.simple
Merge the original landcover with the buffer by selecting pixels where the buffer is null and assigning them the value of the landcover data and assigning 1 to the remaining pixels (where buffer is not null).
if(isnull(A), B, 1)




Input:

Output:


amazing. will try this out. thanks!

@AnaClara updated with a simpler r.mapcalc.simple expression.
